# How to solve com_error when trying to connect to Ansys AnsoftHfss.HfssScriptInterface through win32com.client?

Tags: win32com, ansys

I am trying to test connecting to Ansys `AnsoftHfss.HfssScriptInterface` through `win32com.client`. Code is as below.

```
import win32com.client
print(win32com.client.Dispatch('AnsoftHfss.HfssScriptInterface'))
```

However, I am getting an error => `com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)`.

I have installed and opened the paid version (Academic Research Licence) of Ansys Electronic Desktop 2021.r2.

I have installed the Ansys Electronic Desktop in Windows 11 through Parallels virtual machine in my M1 Pro Mac. More details as below:

Processor: Apple Silicon 3.20 GHz (4 processors), Installed RAM: 8.00 GB, System type: 64-bit operating system, ARM-based processor

I'm not sure whether this could be related to the issue above. When I installed the software, there was an error when the installer was configuring the machine as below. I tried running as the installer as administrator and the the issue still occurred.

[image: Error configuring machine during Ansys electronic desktop installation]

**[UPDATE 19/12/2022]**

I investigated further. I listed all the ProgID in my computer using the PowerShell function Get-ProgID ([PowerShell Gallery | Get-ProgID.ps1 1.0.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Discovery/1.0.1/Content/Get-ProgID.ps1)). I can find the following ProgID for Ansys.

```
ProgID => Location
SIwave.Application =>                         
C:\Program Files\AnsysEM\AnsysEM21.2\Win64\siwave.exe
Simplorer2021.2.Simulator =>                 
C:\Program Files\AnsysEM\AnsysEM21.2\Win64\Sim2000.dll
SIwave.Document =>                          
C:\Program Files\AnsysEM\AnsysEM21.2\Win64\siwave.exe
Simplorer2021.2.CompilerScript =>
C:\Program Files\AnsysEM\AnsysEM21.2\Win64\SimplorerCompEngine.dll
```

I don’t see `AnsoftHfss.HfssScriptInterface` in the list.

I tested the code below:

```
import win32com.client
win32com.client.Dispatch("SIwave.Application")
```

And I successfully get back `<COMObject SIwave.Application>` as output. No errors.

I am not sure why `AnsoftHfss.HfssScriptInterface` is not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because I had installed C++ Redistributables 2015-2022 before running the installer. Uninstalling all C++ Redistibutables and running the Ansys installer which installs it's own C++ Redistributables fixed the issue.